# Open dictionary for English with International Phonetic Alphabet for every word

Tags: data-request, language, english, pronunciation

I'm seeking an openly-licensed dictionary that contains for every word the IPA transcription.

Is such a resource available for English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMU Dict is available online [HERE](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b). It doesn't use the IPA, but it uses Arpabet [link to wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPABET). You could easily convert it from arpabet to IPA. Also, since language is continuously changing it would be impossible to get 'every word'.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a word-IPA mapping list converted from [cmudict](https://github.com/cmusphinx/cmudict):
[menelik3/cmudict-ipa](https://github.com/menelik3/cmudict-ipa), and it also contains the `brown-frequency-list-with-ipa.txt` based on the most frequent 33862 words by the [Brown Corpus](https://archive.org/details/BrownCorpus).